# How to add post category wise into wp_nav_menu programmatically?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a navigation menu with post by category, in every category latest 5 post display.

Cat1  cat2  cat3
  |     |
post1  post2

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**In function.php** 
add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items','display_lasts_ten_posts_for_categories_menu_item',10,3);

```
function display_lasts_ten_posts_for_categories_menu_item( $items, $menu, $args ) {

$menu_order = count($items);
$child_items = array();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
if ( 'category' != $item->object || ('category' == $item->object && get_category_children($item->object_id)) )
continue;
$category_ten_last_posts = array(
'numberposts' => 3,
'cat' => $item->object_id,
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC'
);

foreach ( get_posts( $category_ten_last_posts ) as $post ) {
$post->menu_item_parent = $item->ID;
$post->post_type = 'nav_menu_item';
$post->object = 'custom';
$post->type = 'custom';
$post->menu_order = ++$menu_order;
$post->title = $post->post_title;
$post->url = get_permalink( $post->ID );
$child_items[]= $post;
}
}
return array_merge( $items, $child_items );
}
```

**in header.php**
    wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary','menu_class' => 'display_lasts_ten_posts_for_categories_menu_item',));